# Can't change the encoding xslt to "utf-8"

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xslt

I trying to use xslt to create a bill for restaurant management.
and the code is below, my issue is the out is not in the right font. I already change the encoding to utf-8 but it's still didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"  indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <HTML>
            <body>

                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" width="30%">
                            <b>NHÀ HÀNG SƠN CƯỚC</b>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="20%"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="50%">CONG HOA XA HOI CHU NGHIA VIET NAM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Phiếu số:</td>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                        <td align="center">Độc Lập - Tự Do - Hạnh Phúc</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p align="center">
                    <b>
                        <font size="5">PHIẾU XUẤT</font>
                    </b>
                </p>
                <p></p>
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" width="30%">
                            Số chứng từ: <xsl:value-of select="SALE/TRAN_NO"/>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="5%"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="30%">
                            Mã nhân viên: <xsl:value-of select="SALE/USER_ID"/>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="5%"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="30%">
                            Tổng giá trị:

                            <xsl:variable name="B" select="0"/>
                            <xsl:for-each select="SALE_DETAIL">
                                <xsl:value-of  select="$B + PRICE * AMOUNT"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="B"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            Ngày chứng từ: <xsl:value-of select="SALE/TRAN_DATE"/>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            Mã khách hàng:
                            <xsl:for-each select="DM_CUSTOMERS">
                                <xsl:if test="CUSTOMER_ID=../SALE/CUSTOMER_ID">
                                    <xsl:element name="customer_name">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="CUSTOMER_NAME"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            Số tiền khách đưa: <xsl:value-of select="SALE/TOTAL_CUSTOMER_PAY"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            Loại chứng từ: <xsl:value-of select="SALE/TRAN_ID"/>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            Loại hình xuất:
                            <xsl:for-each select="DM_EXPORT_TYPE">
                                <xsl:if test="EXPORT_TYPE_ID=../SALE/EXPORT_TYPE_ID">
                                    <xsl:element name="EXPORT_TYPE_name">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="EXPORT_TYPE_NAME"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            Tạm tính: <xsl:value-of select="SALE/IS_PROVISIONAL"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            Loại hình thanh toán:
                            <xsl:for-each select="DM_PAY_TYPE">
                                <xsl:if test="PAY_TYPE_ID=../SALE/PAY_TYPE_ID">
                                    <xsl:element name="PAY_TYPE_name">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="PAY_TYPE_NAME"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <p align="left">
                                Ghi chú: <xsl:value-of select="SALE/COMMENT"/>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p></p>
                <table border="1" width="100%" id="table1" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#000000">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="10%">
                            <b>STT</b>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="10%">
                            <b>Mã món</b>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="40%">
                            <b>Tên món</b>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="25%">
                            <b>Đơn giá</b>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="15%">
                            <b>Số lượng</b>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="15%">
                            <b>Thành tiền</b>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="15%">
                            <b>Thuế</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="SALE_DETAIL">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="LIST_ORDER"/>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_ID"/>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_NAME"/>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="PRICE"/>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="AMOUNT"/>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="AMOUNT*PRICE"/>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="VAT_TAX_NAME"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>

                <p></p>
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30%"></td>
                        <td width="30%"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="40%">Hà Nội, ngày...tháng...năm....</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="center">Người lập phiếu</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="center">
                            (<i>Ký, ghi rõ họ tên</i>)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

End when I load the report:

public virtual void LoadReport()
{
try
{
NHMain.Xml.LoadReport();

```
        WB.Url = new Uri(NHMain.StartUpPath + "\\BaoCao\\" + NHMain.Xml.NameTable + ".html");
        WB.Document.Encoding = "utf-8";
        WB.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
        this.ShowDialog();
        WB.Print();
        this.Dispose();
        //
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

}
```

**What should I do to fix it?**

Comment: Is the file itself saved in the correct encoding?

Comment: yes the file itself saved in the correct encoding.

Comment: But not when I see in the preview and print it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `method="html"` to `xsl:output`.